# Launch a pending intent and return to activity that has launch it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent

I'm creating an app android and i'm having a problem with this scenario..
I display a popup, that is an activity that has translucent background and it has a viewpager that it allows to swipe between popups.
Now when I click on this popup I want to launch a pendingIntent (that is not created by me, but by an external application.. for example a pendingIntent delivered by gMail)..

Everything seems to work, but now arrives the problem!
If by clicking on the popup I launch an external activity, like gMail, when I exit from this last one I need to return to the previous activity containing other popups, and this **occurs sometimes but not always**! This is crucial for me, because I have set my activity for popups with tag `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in the manifest file, and so if I'm not able to return to this activity I'll not able to work with other pending popups.

Obviously also the use of `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` is crucial for me.

How can I reach to a solution for this problem?

Here is an example of how I launch a pendingIntent from my popup:

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            if(blablabla){
                try{
                    pi.send(context,0,intent);
                }
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for all!!!

**EDIT**:

My manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="..."
    android:label="..."
    android:theme="..." >
    <activity
        android:name="...ActivityApp"
        android:label="..."
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="...NotificationListener"
        android:label="..."
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- the activity below contains all the popups   -->
    <activity
        android:name="...Popup"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">

    </activity>


</application>
```

And finally the piece of code inside my listener that launch the activity containing popups:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){

    if(sbn.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.gm")){  // GMAIL
            Log.d("GMAIL","ok");
            ...
            Intent gmailIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Popup.class);
            gmailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ...
            getBaseContext().startActivity(gmailIntent);
        }
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. It looks to me like your architecture is flawed. If you launch an external application, the user may leave that application by pressing the HOME button, or by pulling down the notification bar and going to another application. There is no guarantee that it will "come back" to your application. if you have intentionally prevented your application from showing up in the list of recent tasks then there is no way to get back to it. Maybe you should explain what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to create an app that is essentially a service that is listening for new notifications and when this arrive I intercept this one and I show a popup with the info contained in the notification and so on. Now if We think that two notifications arrive, I show two popups. If I'll click on one popup I'll launch the activity that is described by the pendingIntent of its notification. At this point I should press back button to return to my activity and click to the other popup, but when I click the back button I return to the home without my remaining popup.

Comment: Another important information. I'm sure that my activity is not destroyed but is in onPause state! I have checked this with the Logcat.

Comment: But you cannot assume that the user will come back to your activity by "quitting" the app that you launch! He may not be able to do that by just pressing BACK. Android apps don't all work like that. I still think your architecture is flawed. Anyway, post your manifest and maybe I can see why your app isn't reappearing. Also post the code your service uses to launch your "popup" activities.

Comment: Thanks David for all...
The code is in the first post (I have edited it)!

I hope that you can help me!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `launchMode="singleInstance"` for your `Popup` activity. That means that there will only ever be one instance of this activity created. When there are 2 notifications, you will call `startActivity()` 2 times, but the second time it will NOT create another instance of `Popup`, it will simply bring the existing instance of `Popup` to the foreground and call `onNewIntent()` on that instance.

Also, you'll need to specify `taskAffinity=""` in the manifest definition for `Popup` because at the moment `Popup` activity has the same `taskAffinity` as your main activity and this can cause problems if your main activity is already running. If you really need a `singleInstance` activity, then you must ensure that it does not share `taskAffinity` with any other activities in your application.

Since `Popup` is a `singleInstance` activity, when it launches the Gmail activity, that activity will start in a new task (because `singleInstance` prevents launching any other activities into the task starts by the `singleInstance` activity). This may be part of the reason why pressing BACK from Gmail doesn't return to your app.

As I said earlier, I'm afraid your architecture is flawed and you should think about your requirements again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I will think more about my architecture before to proceed with the implementation.

Thanks for all